# How to sent FCM token to django application

Tags: django, webview, push-notification, android-notifications

I have django web application and Android WebView application which simply open url of my web site. I would like to sent notification to users. I know that i need to use django-fcm. But there is problem how to sent FCM token from Android App to my django app and bind it to user. 
There is one idea to sent FCM token to server during user auth sent GET or POST request to server, then put it to the model like `token` and `request.user`. But i don't have any knowladge in Android development. Please if you have some ready examples provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found following solution
In WebView i have created JavaScritp interface to get FCM Token

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public String readToken(){
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        return token;
    }
```

And at login template added folowing

```
<input id = "token" type="text" name="token" hidden>

<script>
    var fcm_token=InterfaceName.readToken();
    document.getElementById('token').value = fcm_token;
</script>
```

So during user login FCM token POST to server together with login and password